# Django / Postgres and random Operational Error - Connection closed

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, transactions, pgbouncer

We are having a hairy Django issue for a while now that keeps coming and going randomly.
Every once in a while we get Operational Error - Connection closed. (see error below).

We are running Django 4.2 / Py3.11 - pgbouncer - PostgreSQL 14 (EC2 + RDS in AWS).

We have never had anything like this, do nothing but plain-vanilla django create/save stuff and started happening once in a while in Django 4 and forward.

Anyone experiencing similar things or have a clue what could be going on???

```
Error message

OperationalError: the connection is closed
  File "django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 308, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 331, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "psycopg/connection.py", line 840, in cursor
    self._check_connection_ok()
  File "psycopg/connection.py", line 479, in _check_connection_ok
    raise e.OperationalError("the connection is closed")

OperationalError: the connection is closed
```

Django DB settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        ...
        "DISABLE_SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS": True,
        "CONN_MAX_AGE": None,
        "CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS": True
    },
 }
```

[gunicorn]

```
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
keepalive = 120
timeout = 120
graceful_timeout = 120
worker_connections = 1000
worker_class = 'sync'
```

[pgbouncer]

```
pool_mode = transaction

default_pool_size = 100
min_pool_size = 20
reserve_pool_size = 30
reserve_pool_timeout = 1

max_client_conn = 10000
server_reset_query =
server_check_delay = 0
server_tls_sslmode = verify-full
server_tls_ca_file = /etc/pgbouncer/xxxxxx

log_connections = 1
log_disconnections = 1
log_pooler_errors = 1
```

pgbouncer logs just repetition of below, nothing else:

```
Apr 09 14:54:13 pgbouncer[719032]: stats: 20 xacts/s, 20 queries/s, in 25996 B/s, out 46656 B/s, xact 3349 us, query 3343 us, wait 24409 us
 Apr 09 14:55:13 pgbouncer[719032]: stats: 40 xacts/s, 40 queries/s, in 61480 B/s, out 229186 B/s, xact 3216 us, query 3162 us, wait 46999 us
 Apr 09 14:56:13 pgbouncer[719032]: stats: 22 xacts/s, 22 queries/s, in 34561 B/s, out 77043 B/s, xact 3076 us, query 3060 us, wait 22044 us
 Apr 09 14:57:13 pgbouncer[719032]: stats: 26 xacts/s, 26 queries/s, in 42978 B/s, out 185932 B/s, xact 3422 us, query 3407 us, wait 29930 us
 Apr 09 14:57:26 pgbouncer[719032]: C-0x560e05b89020: pgbouncer/netdata@unix(1806513):6432 closing because: client close request (age=600s)
 Apr 09 14:57:26 pgbouncer[719032]: C-0x560e05b89020: pgbouncer/netdata@unix(1806513):6432 login attempt: db=pgbouncer user=netdata tls=no
 Apr 09 14:58:13 pgbouncer[719032]: stats: 21 xacts/s, 21 queries/s, in 37727 B/s, out 211338 B/s, xact 3593 us, query 3523 us, wait 27558 us
 Apr 09 14:58:26 pgbouncer[719032]: S-0x560e05b97210: shoot_dev/shoot_dev@172.31.29.188:5432 closing because: server lifetime over (age=3600s)
```

Postgres logs nothing but checkpoints started/checkpoint complete...

Comment: What is in the pgbouncer log for this event?  What is the PostgreSQL log?

Comment: added logs above above

Comment: This is happening to us as well.  Usually the stack trace will show the culprit is application code, however, here it's happening just with out of the box Django admin. Anyone with an answer?

Comment: How can no one else be encountering this?  Any insight would be appreciated!

django==4.2.1
psycopg==3.1.8
# psycopg2==2.9.6 (also tried this)
PostgreSQL 14

Of note we are also using Celery and Celery Beat but this is typical of our stacks.  The errors are outside of application code.  A simple out of the box Django admin list view for a model can cause it...it's totally intermittent, but 33% of the time or more.

Comment: Same issue here. Similar configuration: Django 4.2 and Postgres 14. Dockerized environment on the same VM. Totally random but hopefully quite infrequent.

Comment: Same here with Django 3.1 and psycopg2. Now updated to Django 4.2 and psycopg v3 with same result. Database is Postgres v14 served with gunicorn via nginx.